# Collection view cell navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

Dear fellow coders please help me. I started to learn Swift 2 months ago and this will be my first app if I will be able to finish...
First of all, I don't use storyboard. In my app, there are collection views in main window. When you tap the image in the cells, for example the cat image in the cat cell, Cat.swift file should open. But I can't implement it yet. And in the same way if you tap the dog image, Dog.swift file should be viewed. Here is the code.

this is the main screen when you open the app:

```
import UIKit

class FeaturedAnimalsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var animalCategories: [AnimalCategory]?

    private let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        animalCategories = AnimalCategory.sampleAnimalCategories()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func showAnimalDetailForAnimal(animal: Animal) {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let animalDetailController = AnimalDetailController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        animalDetailController.animal = animal
        navigationController?.pushViewController(animalDetailController, animated: true)
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = animalCategories?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        cell.featuredAnimalsController = self

        cell.animalCategory = animalCategories?[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 230)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } 
}
```

This is the CategoryCell:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var featuredAnimalsController: FeaturedAnimalsController?

    var animalCategory: AnimalCategory? {
        didSet {
            if let name = animalCategory?.name {
                nameLabel.text = name
            }
        }
    }

    private let cellId = "animalCellId"

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = animalCategory?.animals?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! AnimalCell
        cell.animal = animalCategory?.animals?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height - 32)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 14, bottom: 0, right: 14)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let animal = animalCategory?.animals![indexPath.item] {
            featuredAnimalsController?.showAnimalDetailForAnimal(animal: animal)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Cardiology"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        //label.numberOfLines = 1  --> DEFAULT
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let animalsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .clear

        animalsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        animalsCollectionView.delegate = self

        animalsCollectionView.register(AnimalCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(animalsCollectionView)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-14-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": animalsCollectionView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[nameLabel(30)][v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": animalsCollectionView, "nameLabel": nameLabel]))

    }


}

class AnimalCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var animal: Animal? {
        didSet {
            if let name = animal?.name {
                nameLabel.text = name
            }
            categoryLabel.text = animal?.category

            if let imageName = animal?.imageName {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .clear

        addSubview(categoryLabel)
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(nameLabel)

        categoryLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.width + 38, width: frame.width, height: 20)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.width)
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.width + 2, width: frame.width, height: 40)

    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        //iv.image = UIImage(named: "cat")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let categoryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()  
}
```

This is the animal category model:

```
import UIKit

class AnimalCategory: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var animals: [Animal]?

    static func sampleAnimalCategories() -> [AnimalCategory] {


        let catFamilyCategory = AnimalCategory()
        catFamilyCategory.name = "Cat Family"
        var catFamilyAnimals = [Animal]()

        let catAnimal = Animal()
        catAnimal.name = "Cat"
        catAnimal.imageName = "cat"
        catAnimal.category = "Lovely"
        //catAnimal.dvcName = Cat.self()
        catFamilyAnimals.append(catAnimal)

        catFamilyCategory.animals = catFamilyAnimals



        let dogFamilyCategory = AnimalCategory()
        dogFamilyCategory.name = "Dog Family"
        var dogFamilyAnimals = [Animal]()

        let dogAnimal = Animal()
        dogAnimal.name = "Dog"
        dogAnimal.imageName = "dog"
        dogAnimal.category = "Friendly"
        //dogAnimal.dvcName = Dog.self
        dogFamilyAnimals.append(dogAnimal)

        dogFamilyCategory.animals = dogFamilyAnimals


        return [catFamilyCategory, dogFamilyCategory]
    }
}
```

This is the animal model:

```
import UIKit

class Animal: NSObject {

    //var id: NSNumber?
    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var imageName: String?
    //var dvc: AnimalDetailController?

}
```

This is the animal detail controller and sample cat.swift:

```
import UIKit

class AnimalDetailController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var animal: Animal? {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.title = animal?.name
        }
    }
}

class Cat: AnimalDetailController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .brown
    }
}
```

After some changes thanks to @Paulw11, here is the code to present specific detail view controller for each animal:

```
func showAnimalDetailFor(_ animal: Animal) {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        var dvc = animal.dvc
        dvc = AnimalDetailController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.show(dvc, sender: self)
    }
```

Here is the animal and animal category model:

```
struct Animal {

    let name: String
    let category: String
    let imageName: String
    let dvc: AnimalDetailController

}

struct AnimalCategory {

    var name: String
    private var _animals = [Animal]()

    var animals: [Animal] {
        get {
            return self._animals
        }
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static var sampleAnimalCategories: [AnimalCategory] = {

        var dogFamily = AnimalCategory(name: "Dog Family")
        dogFamily.addAnimal(Animal(name: "Dog", category: "Friendly", imageName: "dog", dvc: DogDetailViewController()))

        var catFamily = AnimalCategory(name: "Cat Family")
        catFamily.addAnimal(Animal(name: "Cat", category: "Lovely", imageName: "cat", dvc: CatDetailViewController()))

        let categories = [dogFamily,catFamily]
        return categories
    }()

    mutating func addAnimal(_ animal: Animal) {
        self._animals.append(animal)
    }

}
```

And animal detail controller class:

```
class AnimalDetailController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var animal: Animal? {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.title = animal?.name
        }
    }
}
```

I don't wont transfer data between view controllers. I am planning to make specific swift files for each animal in the cell and then when you tp their icon I want those swift file to show up. And of course I am using nav controller and set it in app delegate.

Please help me. Thank you all.

Comment: Why would you make specific classes for each animal?  In general you would try and abstract the code from the data as much as possible.

Comment: This code works properly... For example, when I tap to cat image, I want to see a collection view with 5 cells; but if I tap to dog image, I want to see 3 cells. And among those cells data will be irrelevant. So I think I can't navigate this from a single database. Thats why ı chose to make different swift file for each animal. Category cell is different collection views in the main page by the way.

Comment: to cut the long story short, I am asking the code algorithm to see the Cat.swift (which is a separate collection view) after tapping to the image named "cat", or tapping to cell of the cat

Comment: You can store a reference to `Cat.self` and `Dog.self` in your data model and then call `init()` on that property to get an instance of the view controller e.g. `let catVC = Cat.self` and then `let catVCInstance = catVC.init()` but, as I said, this sort of tight coupling between data and code is poor design

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would caution against tightly coupling your data and your code, but you can do what you want by storing a reference to the view controller class in your data model; You almost had it correct in your commented code; you just don't need the `()` after `self`.

It is best practice to use structs if you don't need mutability, so your `Animal` and `AnimalCategory` objects could be structs.  You can also avoid all of those optionals.

```
struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let imageName: String
    let dvc: AnimalDetailController.Type
}

struct AnimalCategory {

    var name: String

    private var _animals = [Animal]()

    var animals: [Animal] {
        get {
            return self._animals
        }
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static var sampleAnimalCategories: [AnimalCategory] = {

        var dogs = AnimalCategory(name: "Dog Family")
        dogs.addAnimal(Animal(name: "Dog", category: "Friendly", imageName: "dog", dvc: DogDetailViewController.self))

        var cats = AnimalCategory(name: "Cat Family")
        cats.addAnimal(Animal(name: "Cat", category: "Lovely", imageName: "cat", dvc: CatDetailViewController.self))

        let categories = [dogs,cats]
        return categories
    }()

    mutating func addAnimal(_ animal: Animal) {
        self._animals.append(animal)
    }

}
```

Then your `showAnimalDetailForAnimal` will be something like:

```
func showAnimalDetailFor(_ animal: Animal) {
    let dvc = animal.dvc.init() 
    self.show(dvc, sender: self)
}
```

There is also a lot of cleaning up you can do with regard to your use of optionals.  For example, `animals`, and `animalCategories` could all be implicitly unwrapped optionals.

You won't be able to have your `AnimalDetailViewController` subclass `UICollectionViewController` since you can't initialise with a layout.  You will need to subclass `UIViewController` and add the collection view in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you but after doing everything wrote, I am in the same spot. The problem is, when I tap to the cat image, AnimalDetailController shows up, not CatDetailViewController (swift file specific for the cat). I realized it after typing a background color to AnimalDetailController. In my project, CatDVC and DogDVC are collectionviewcontrollers and they are subclass of AnimalDetailController. But I can't go beyond AnimalDetailController yet... Thank you for your answer btw. I still have the previous

Comment: ***version as a backup if anyone wants to type their own solution

Comment: Edit your question to show your `showAnimalDetailFor` code or whatever function you use to instantiate and present your detail view controller.

Comment: Your `showAnimalDetailFor` is instantiating an instance of `AnimalDetailController` - That is not what my code does.  Use my `showAnimalDetailFor`

Comment: I tried: func showAnimalDetailFor(_ animal: Animal) {
        let dvc = animal.dvc
        self.show(dvc, sender: self)
    }      this because at first I couldn't even launch it but when I launch with this code, it crashes after tapping to an image because I am trying to instantiate a collection view and I don't have any layout for it. Thats why I tried to put a layout in showAnimalDetailFor function

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but you need to initialise the right class - see my update.  You could also just use a `UIViewController` rather than a `UICollectionViewController` and add an instance of `UICollectionView` with an appropriate layout in the `viewDidLoad`.  I will hardly ever use `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` as you cannot easily add additional UI elements to them.

Comment: Right, you will need to subclass `UIViewController` and add the collection view in `viewDidLoad`.